# htaccess rewrite - redirect to another subdomain is looping

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, rewriting

I'm trying to redirect two kind of urls to a subdomain and all the others to my main domain.
A concrete example :

- "my account" pages starting by /my-account/* and subscription page must be redirected to https://my-account.domaim.com. The uri must be kept.
- all others like /news or the homepage must be seen on www.domain.com only

Here is what I have tried until now :

```
# All urls except my-account/* and subscription are redirected to the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-account\.domain\.(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^my-account/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subscription$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.%1/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

# subscription page is redirected to my-account subdomain   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^subscription$ https://my-account.domain.%1/subscription[L,QSA,R=301]

# All my-account/* pages are redirected to my-account subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^my-account/(.*)$ https://my-account.domain.%1/my-account/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Each rules work independently but if i try all of them together i'm stuck in an infinite loop.

Is anyone have an idea how to prevent it ?

Answer (score 0):

The rules look fine, but you have a missing space in your 2nd rule:

```
RewriteRule ^subscription$ https://my-account.domain.%1/subscription[L,QSA,R=301]
#  -----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

But you can probably combine them into a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(subscription|my-account/.*)$ https://my-account.domain.%1/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Also make sure you're clearing your cache when you test, as 301 redirects are permanent and the browser will cache them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer !
The typos was from my copy/paste and the combination works but doesn't change anything to the problem with the other rules. I keep it for later ;)

I tried a reversed rules like this :

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-account\.domain\.(.+)$ [NC] 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subscription$  [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-account/  [NC] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-account.domain.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It also works but not in combination with the other. it doesn't loop anymore but if i try something like http/www.domain.com/subscription i'm redirected to www.domain.com with the url truncated. It seems that the Rewrite conditions aren't correctly recognized but still can't find why ...